# String comparison with R

Tags: r, regex, string, merge

I have two datasets that I want to link (inner_join) with a common key which is a string. The problem is that in one of the two dataset the key is not complete, but this uncomplete key is included in the other one, like the following example:

```
key for 1st dataset: PV955--075P412171042-- 
and for the 2nd:     PV955--???P412171042--
```

The `???` represents numbers that are missing, so my question is can we do like a string comparison/inclusion to check if the characters of my 2nd key are included my 1st key and do the join on this if yes?

Idk if the issue is clear, and thanks for the answers.

Comment: Depending on how unique the ID patterns are..., maybe just join on substring `P412171042`?

Comment: if your datasets are small enough you can merge both, compute the distance between each couple and keep the smallest distance for every key of dataset one. the package `fuzzyjoin` might allow you to do it elegantly (but I think it still builds the big table under the hood). If the 3 interrogation points are always at the same place it is trivial however. Your question would benefit from a bigger example.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Indeed the missing numbers are always at the same place, so it seems that your fuzzyjoin can do the job. 

I'll try this. 

Thanks again all!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer without seeing your data, however you can try this:

```
library(stringr)
> str_detect("075P412171042","P412171042")
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: This can be interesting too. I might try if fuzzyjoin doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In base R with regular expressions :

```
key1 <- "PV955--075P412171042--"
key2 <- "PV955--???P412171042--"
key2re <- gsub("--...", "--...", key2)
grepl(key2re, key1)
## [1] TRUE
```

Replace the 3 unknown characters after "--" by dots meaning any character in regular expressions.
Then grepl check if the two strings match.